# runOnUiThread() and infinite loop on Android

Tags: java, multithreading, android-runonuithread

I do not understand the behaviour of my code. To summarize, I have an editText (variable hours in my code) that start with "00". I am creating a thread which prevents this editText to not have 2 digit. Let s assume that this editText cannot have more than 2 digits. What I am doing is that I create a thread. In this thread, whenever this editText does not have 2 digits(so 1 digit), I add to it a "0".

However, whenever I just put one digit on the editText, it is getting crazy and go into an infinite loop and other stuff that I don't understand. Here is my code:

```
Thread digitLessThanTwoThread;
EditText hours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hours);
digitLessThanTwoThread= new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                while(true) {
                    if (hours.getText().toString().length() != 2 && !hours.isFocused()) {
                        main_activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                hours.setText("0" + hours.getText().toString());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        digitLessThanTwoThread.start();
```

Moreover, at the end, The editText hours displayed "00". 
I also get a message "suspending all threads took: XXX seconds" before doing anything actually!

Comment: You may see life quality improvements if you never type `while ( true ) ` again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here. First, the simple one:

```
while(true)
```

This will run the thread at full power until as you seem to be noticing, the OS steps in to stop the runaway thread. You should instead add an `addTextChangedListener()` listener, for example.

The more complex one is:

```
main_activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        hours.setText("0" + hours.getText().toString());
    }
});
```

I think you are assuming that this is executed synchronously, that is the `setText()` is executed before `runOnUiThread()` returns. However, it is asynchronous, so next time round the loop your `if` is still true, and you queue another action on the UI thread to set the text and so on, so the UI thread may never get a chance to run until the OS steps in to halt the runaway thread.